# Why is the resolution of a tunneling microscope not limited by the wavelength of the electrons?

Tags: diffraction, wavelength, quantum-tunneling, microscopy

Why is the resolution of a tunneling microscope not limited by the wavelength of the electrons? Is it impossible for the electrons that are tunneling across the gap to appear somewhere in the gap, with momentum, and behave as a wave?

Comment: Resolution you're referring to is side-to-side resolution, yes? Whereas the wavelength of the electron is an uncertainty in the direction of travel, up-down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tunneling is characterized by the wavefunction in the forbidden region having an imaginary longitudinal component of the wavevector. This makes the wavevector, for a given wavelength $\lambda$, to be smaller in magnitude than the projection of the wavevector onto the surface of the sample.

Suppose the sample is in the $xy$ plane. Then, in the gap between the sample and the probe $k_z^2<0,$ and

$$k=\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2-|k_z|^2}.$$

If we used this value of $k$ in a scanning electron microscope (which uses propagating electrons instead of evanescent-mode ones), the wavelength would be

$$\lambda=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2-|k_z|^2}}.\tag{1}$$

But in a scanning tunneling microscope the full wavevector is not relevant: we don't rely on the propagation of the electron wave, instead we intercept it near the interface as an evanescent wave. The "borrowed" part of the wavevector that led to $k_z^2<0$ is put into the $xy$ projection of $\vec k$, effectively increasing the resolution in the $xy$ plane. Thus, the relevant property of the evanescent mode is the wavelength corresponding to $k_{xy}$:

$$\lambda'=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2}}.\tag{2}$$

We can see that for an evanescent wave the effective wavelength $\lambda'<\lambda.$ This is what gives a scanning tunneling microscope higher resolution than a same-wavelength scanning electron microscope.

---

This same principle of breaking the resolution limit is used in [near-field scanning optical microscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-field_scanning_optical_microscope), which operates on photons instead of electrons.